# Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{x(x+y)}$

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory

I'm interested in the following integral
$$
f(a,b) = \int dx \int dy e^{i a x } e^{i b y} \frac{1}{x ( x + y ) } 
$$
The integral is over the reals. We use the property
$$
\int dx e^{i a x} \frac{1}{x} = i \pi s(a) , \qquad s(a) = \text{sign}(a) . 
$$
Let's the do the $y$ integral first followed by the $x$ one. Then,
\begin{align}
f(a,b) &= \int dx  e^{i a x } \frac{1}{x} \int dy e^{i b y} \frac{1}{x + y} \\
&= \int dx  e^{i a x } \frac{1}{x} \int dy e^{i b ( y - x ) } \frac{1}{y} \\
&= \int dx  e^{i ( a - b ) x } \frac{1}{x} \int dy e^{i b y } \frac{1}{y} \\
&= ( i \pi )^2 s(a-b) s(b) . 
\end{align}
Instead, let us do the $x$ integral first following by the $y$ one. To do this, we write
$$
\frac{1}{x(x+y)}  = \frac{1}{xy} - \frac{1}{y(y+x)} 
$$
Then,
\begin{align}
f(a,b) &= \int dy e^{i b y} \int dx  e^{i a x } \left[ \frac{1}{xy} - \frac{1}{y(y+x)}  \right] \\
&=  \int dy e^{i b y} \int dx  e^{i a x }  \frac{1}{xy} - \int dy e^{i b y} \int dx  e^{i a x } 
 \frac{1}{y(y+x)} \\
&=  \int dy e^{i b y} \frac{1}{y} \int dx  e^{i a x } \frac{1}{x} - \int dy e^{i b y} \frac{1}{y} \int dx  e^{i a x } \frac{1}{y + x }  \\
&= ( i \pi )^2 s(a)s(b) - \int dy e^{i ( b - a ) y} \frac{1}{y} \int dx  e^{i a x } 
 \frac{1}{x} \\
&= ( i \pi )^2 s(a)s(b) - (i \pi )^2 s(b-a) s(a) 
\end{align}
The two answers aren't equal - rather they differ by a constant
$$
s(a-b) s(b) \color{red}{+ 1} = s(a)s(b) -  s(b-a) s(a) 
$$
What's going on?

PS - I know I'm being pretty lax about many things so some guidance will be helpful.

Comment: I notice that the left hand side of $\frac{1}{x(x+y)}  = \frac{1}{xy} - \frac{1}{y(y+x)}$ is defined when $y=0$ if $x \neq 0$ while the right hand side is not. Perhaps the identity is not valid in a distributional sense, and the difference is $\delta(x)\delta(y)$ which would explain the difference $1$ of the transforms.

Comment: I agree, your functions are not integrable here, so you cannot use Fubini theorem or linearity of the integral, for example. In general, you have to use principal value distributions to manipulate integrals when functions are not integrable.

Comment: This is actually an interesting to compute that rigorously. $\frac{1}{x(x+y)}$ being not integrable, it is not a tempered distribution, so **its Fourier transform is not well defined**. So the first question is what is the tempered distribution associated to the function $\frac{1}{x(x+y)}$? Only after that we will be able to compute the Fourier transform rigorously.

Comment: @LL3.14. If $\frac{1}{x(x+y)}$ were a nice function then we would have
$$
\left< \frac{1}{x(x+y)}, \varphi(x,y) \right>
= \left\{ \begin{align}x&=\xi\\ y&=\eta-\xi\end{align} \right\}
= \left< \frac{1}{\xi\eta}, \varphi(\xi, \eta-\xi) \right>
$$
suggesting that we define
$$
\left< \frac{1}{x(x+y)}, \varphi(x,y) \right>
= \left< \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}\otimes\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{y}, \varphi(x, y-x) \right>
$$

Comment: Have you got any solution to this from outside of Math.SE? I've thought about it but haven't solved it yet. The difference of the Fourier transforms suggests a difference $\delta(x,y)$ of the distributions, but I haven't been able to show that.

Answer (score 1):

I can now show that $\frac{1}{x(x+y)} + \frac{1}{(x+y)y} - \frac{1}{xy}$ does not vanish under integration but has a "residue" of $\pi^2$ at origin.

Let $\delta,\epsilon>0$ and integrate each term over the rectangle $R=[-\delta,\delta]\times[-\epsilon,\epsilon].$

For $\frac{1}{xy}$ this is trivial:
$$
\iint_{R} \frac{1}{xy} \ dx \ dy
= \left( \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \frac{1}{x} \ dx \right) \left( \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} \frac{1}{y} \ dy \right)
= 0.
$$
Note that we are here using the principal value integral.

For $\frac{1}{x(x+y)}$ we get
$$
\iint_{R} \frac{1}{x(x+y)} \ dx \ dy
= \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \frac{1}{x} \left( \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} \frac{1}{x+y} \ dy \right) \ dx
= \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \frac{1}{x} (\ln|x+\epsilon| - \ln|x-\epsilon|) \ dx
\\
= \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \frac{1}{x} \ln|x+\epsilon| \ dx - \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \frac{1}{x} \ln|x-\epsilon| \ dx
.
$$
Now, setting $x=\epsilon t$ we get
$$
\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \frac{1}{x} \ln|x+\epsilon| \ dx
= \int_{-\delta/\epsilon}^{\delta/\epsilon} \frac{1}{\epsilon t} \ln|\epsilon t+\epsilon| \ \epsilon \ dt
= \int_{-\delta/\epsilon}^{\delta/\epsilon} \frac{1}{t} (\ln|t+1| + \ln\epsilon) \ dt
\\
= \int_{-\delta/\epsilon}^{\delta/\epsilon} \frac{1}{t} \ln|t+1| \ dt + \int_{-\delta/\epsilon}^{\delta/\epsilon} \frac{1}{t} \ dt \  \ln\epsilon
= \int_{-\delta/\epsilon}^{\delta/\epsilon} \frac{1}{t} \ln|t+1| \ dt
$$
since the integral for the $\ln\epsilon$ term vanishes.

Likewise, setting $x=-\epsilon t$ we get
$$
\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \frac{1}{x} \ln|x-\epsilon| \ dx
= \int_{-\delta/\epsilon}^{\delta/\epsilon} \frac{1}{t} \ln|t+1| \ dt.
$$

Thus,
$$
\iint_{R} \frac{1}{x(x+y)} \ dx \ dy
= 2\int_{-\delta/\epsilon}^{\delta/\epsilon} \frac{1}{t} \ln|t+1| \ dt.
$$

For $\frac{1}{(x+y)y}$ we similarly get
$$
\iint_{R} \frac{1}{(x+y)y} \ dx \ dy
= 2\int_{-\epsilon/\delta}^{\epsilon/\delta} \frac{1}{t} \ln|t+1| \ dt.
$$

Thus,
$$
\iint_R \left( \frac{1}{x(x+y)} + \frac{1}{(x+y)y} - \frac{1}{xy} \right) \ dx \ dy
= 2 \left( \int_{-\epsilon/\delta}^{\epsilon/\delta}+\int_{-\delta/\epsilon}^{\delta/\epsilon} \right) \frac{1}{t} \ln|t+1| \ dt
$$
which is of the form
$$
I := 2 \left( \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha}+\int_{-1/\alpha}^{1/\alpha} \right) \frac{1}{t} \ln|t+1| \ dt.
$$

Using substitution $t=1/s$ we get
$$
\int_{-1/\alpha}^{1/\alpha} \frac{1}{t} \ln|t+1| \ dt
= \lim_{\eta\to 0}\left(\int_{-1/\alpha}^{-\eta}+\int_{\eta}^{1/\alpha}\right) \frac{1}{t} \ln|t+1| \ dt
= \lim_{\eta\to 0}\left(\int_{-\alpha}^{-1/\eta}+\int_{1\eta}^{\alpha}\right) \frac{1}{1/s} \ln\left|\frac{s+1}{s}\right| \ \frac{-ds}{s^2}
= -\lim_{\eta\to 0} \left(\int_{-\alpha}^{-1/\eta}+\int_{1/\eta}^{\alpha}\right) \frac{1}{s} \ln|s+1| \ ds + \lim_{\eta\to 0} \left(\int_{-\alpha}^{-1/\eta}+\int_{1/\eta}^{\alpha}\right) \frac{1}{s} \ln|s| \ ds
= \lim_{\eta\to 0} \left(\int_{-1/\eta}^{-\alpha}+\int_{\alpha}^{1/\eta}\right) \frac{1}{s} \ln|s+1| \ ds
$$
since the second limit vanishes.

Thus,
$$
I 
= 2 \lim_{\eta\to 0} \left( \int_{-1/\eta}^{-\alpha} + \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} + \int_{\alpha}^{1/\eta} \right) \frac{1}{s} \ln|s+1| \ ds
= 2 \lim_{\eta\to 0} \int_{-1/\eta}^{1\eta} \frac{1}{s} \ln|s+1| \ ds
$$
which is not dependent on $\alpha.$

Taking $\alpha=1$ we get
$$
I 
= 2 \left( \int_{-1}^{1}+\int_{-1}^{1} \right) \frac{1}{t} \ln|t+1| \ dt
= 4 \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{t} \ln|t+1| \ dt
= 4 \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{t} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}t^k}{k} \ dt
\\
= 4 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{t^{k-1}}{k} \ dt
= 4 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{1^{k}-(-1)^{k}}{k^2}
= 4 \sum_{k=1\\ \text{$k$ odd}}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{2}{k^2}
= 8 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}
= 8 \cdot \frac{\pi^2}{8}
= \pi^2.
$$

Thus, over every rectangle $[-\delta,\delta]\times[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ the integral of $\frac{1}{x(x+y)} + \frac{1}{(x+y)y} - \frac{1}{xy}$ has value $\pi^2.$ This means that the sum at least has a term $\pi^2 \ \delta(x,y).$ There could also be derivatives of $\delta(x,y)$ but the Fourier transform in the question shows that this is not the case.